# Resolving module exports in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

I have the following folders and files in my project:

```
src/
  - services/
    -- index.ts
    -- legacy.ts
  - index.ts
  ... other project files and folders
```

`legacy.ts` file is a large file that contains many functions. All these functions are exported from that file like so:

```
export function legacyFn1() { // code here }
... other functions in the file
```

I want to define a `Proxy` that intercepts all calls for these functions and perform some tasks before calling the said function. To do that, I added the following code in `services/index.ts` file:

```js
import * as legacyServiceFns from './legacy'

Object.keys(legacyServiceFns).map((fn) => {
  ;(exports as any)[fn] = new Proxy((legacyServiceFns as any)[fn], {
    apply(target, that, args) {
      // use this trap to perform/delegate as needed
      
    }
  })
})
```

In the above snippet, I am trying to dynamically set `exports` with a proxy around each of the legacy functions imported. When I try to import a legacy function from `services` module, I get errors that there are no such functions in the module like in the snippet below:

```js
import { legacyFn1 } from './services'
```

How can I resolve this issue? I tried adding a custom typings file inside the `services` folder and modifying `typeRoot` compiler options to point to that directory but that did not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a similar task recently, and this is what has worked for me (adapted do your case):

```js
import * as legacyServiceFns from './legacy';
    
const _export: typeof legacyServiceFns = Object.fromEntries(
  Object.entries(legacyServiceFns).map(([name, fn]) => [
    name,
    new Proxy(fn, {
      apply(target, that, args) {
        console.log({target, that, args});
        // use this trap to perform/delegate as needed      
      }
    }),
  ])
) as any;

export = _export;
```

So, what it does:

1. Imports all legacy functions as an object, and this object has proper types.
2. Makes new object of the same type (keys are function names, values are functions themselves) by wrapping each function with `Proxy`.
3. Exports everything in a typed manner, so other modules that consume this one will see exactly same types as in `./legacy`. IDE autocompletion should work just fine.

[Here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html#export--and-import--require) you can read more about `export` assignment.